# How can I use logistic regression model to test data that is imputed in some cases?

Tags: machine-learning, logistic, neural-networks, missing-data

I trained a logistic regression model and I want to test it.

In some cases, I have missing features value.

Is it still possible to test it?
Or I must fill the missing values?

Comment: If you leave the missing data in place, you'll have to multiply a missing value by a coefficient. How do you propose to do that multiplication?

Comment: Good question.
The question is there a way to somehow use the other weights in the equation to compensate for those missing values.
So, for example, I want to evaluate test data, and it has 6 values out of the 7 features. I can't multiply the 7th  feature with the weight as there is missing value there. so I take the weight of the 7th feature and somehow spread it across the other weights of the equation to compensate.
Is this possible?

Comment: Sounds like an interesting research topic. I look forward to reading about your solution to this problem.

Answer (score 0):

It is depending on how do you define "test it".

If you want to test it to see if it works on non-missing cases, just remove the data with missing features, and test it as usual.

On the other hand, if you want to see if it works for data with missing features, then you may need to think about how to pre-process data before feeding into model.

Question to think about: in this case, are you testing your imputation algorithm or logistic regression?

Comment: Good question.
The question is there a way to somehow use the other weights in the equation to compensate for those missing values.
So, for example, I want to evaluate test data, and it has 6 values out of the 7 features. I can't multiply the 7th  feature with the weight as there is missing value there. so I take the weight of the 7th feature and somehow spread it across the other weights of the equation to compensate.
Is this possible?